# How do I create user-groups in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I was trying to find this solution online through google, but maybe I am not using the right terminology so I keep getting directed to user roles.

Right now I have reports on SSRS. I want to create a user group which holds all the window ids of users from a specific group in the company. For example all the sales reps will have a group MyDomain\SalesReps. All managers will have a group called MyDomain\Managers. This way when I have a new report I just have to input the user-group in the security setting instead of adding each employee's windows id into the permissions/security list.

Hope I communicated that clearly, if not let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You create the groups in Active Directory, not in SSRS.  Then an AD group can subscribe to an SSRS report.